# Возникла проблема с кодом Display

Tags: c++, display

```
//Source.cpp
#include "Complex.h"
#include "Complex.cpp"

int main()
{
    Complex A;
    Complex B(2.5, 5);
    Read(A);
    cout << "A = ";
    Display(A);
    cout << "B = ";
    Display(B);
    cout << "A - B = ";
    A.sub(A, B);
    cout << "A / B = ";
    A.div(A, B);
    cout << "Conjugate A = ";
    A.conj(A);

}

//Complex.h
#pragma once
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;


class Complex
{
private:
    double x;
    double y;
public:

    Complex();
    Complex(double f, double s);
    Complex(const Complex&);
    int get_x() const { return x; }
    int get_y() const { return y; }
    void set_x(double value) { x = value; }
    void set_y(double value) { y = value; }
    Complex sub(Complex&, Complex&);
    Complex div(Complex&, Complex&);
    Complex conj(Complex&);
    void Display(Complex& R);
    void Read(Complex& R);

};

//Complex.cpp
#include "Complex.h"

Complex::Complex()
{
    x = 0;
    y = 0;
}

Complex::Complex(double f, double s)
{
    x = f;
    y = s;
}

Complex::Complex(const Complex& R)
{
    x = R.x;
    y = R.y;
}

Complex Complex::sub(Complex& R1, Complex& R2)
{
    Complex T = Complex(R1.x - R2.x, R1.y - R2.y);
    Display(T);
    return Complex();
}

Complex Complex::div(Complex& R1, Complex& R2)
{
    Complex T = Complex((R1.x * R2.x + R1.y * R2.y) / (R2.x * R2.x + R2.y * R2.y), (R2.x * R1.y - R1.x * R2.y) / (R2.x * R2.x + R2.y * R2.y));
    Display(T);
    return Complex();
}

Complex Complex::conj(Complex& R)
{
    Complex T = Complex(R.x, R.y * -1);
    Display(T);
    return Complex();
}

void Display(Complex& R)
{
    cout << R.x;
    if (R.y < 0)
        cout << R.y;
    else
        cout << "+" << R.y;

    cout << "i" << endl;
}

void Read(Complex& R)
{
    double N1, N2;
    cout << "enter X "; cin >> N1;
    cout << "enter Y "; cin >> N2;
    Complex T(N1, N2);
    R = T;
}
```

Comment: Нужно сделать програму которая может:                                                                                  
Комплексное число представляются парой действительных чисел (x, y), где поля
• x - действительная часть,
• y - мнимая часть.
Реализовать класс Complex для работы с комплексными числами. Обязательно
должны быть реализованы методы:
• вычитание sub () (x1, y1) - (x2, y2) = (x1 - x2, y1 - y2)
• деления div () (x1, y1) / (x2, y2) = (x1 · x2 + y1 · y2, x2 · y1 - x1 · y2) / (x2 2 + y2 2)
• комплексно сопряженное число conj () conj (x, y) = (x, -y).

Comment: Ну а проблема-то какая?

Comment: Не работает void Display в Complex.cpp

Comment: Что значит «не работает»?

Comment: R.x  R.y  выдает ошибку

Comment: Какую ошибку? .

Comment: Error C2248 'Complex::y': cannot access private member declared in class 'Complex' Complex.cpp 48

Comment: Путаница между глобальной функцией и функцией-членом. Глобальная не сможет достучаться до непубличных полей класса

Comment: Как это можно исправить?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Начните с того, что уберите этот ужас —

```
#include "Complex.cpp"
```

из `Source.cpp`. Вам надо ошибок двойного определения?

Затем таки решите — `Display` и `Read` функции-члены или нет?

Если нет — сделайте их друзьями:

```
    Complex div(Complex&, Complex&);
    Complex conj(Complex&);
    friend void Display(Complex& R);
    friend void Read(Complex& R);
};
```

Если же да — объявление класса меняем как

```
    Complex div(Complex&, Complex&);
    Complex conj(Complex&);
    void Display();
    void Read();
};
```

в `Complex.cpp` сделайте их членами —

```
void Complex::Display()
{
    cout << x;
    if (y < 0)
        cout << y;
    else
        cout << "+" << y;
    cout << "i" << endl;
}

void Complex::Read()
{
    double N1, N2;
    cout << "enter X "; cin >> N1;
    cout << "enter Y "; cin >> N2;
    Complex T(N1, N2);
    *this = T;
}
```

и вызывайте их верно —

```
A.Read();
cout << "A = ";
A.Display();
cout << "B = ";
B.Display();
```

И все

```
Display(T);
```

замените на

```
T.Display();
```

Так оно будет компилироваться.

Будет ли работать — не знаю, с этой точки зрения (верно ли написан класс) я ваш код не смотрел.

Comment: Спасибо, все работает